# Should we ban joke “languages”?

Tags: discussion

I see lately lots of answers like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22998/3358) that use joke “languages” like HQ9+. Should we add a requirement that the language should be sufficiently complex?

Comment: Related: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny

Answer (score 1):

*This is just my opinion as a user, not as a moderator.*

I think HQ9+ is more or less grandfathered in. Its applicability to most golfing challenges is very limited.

As for new languages, I'd like to see languages that are general-purpose and not tailored specifically for a certain class of programming problems. For example, GolfScript is actually general-purpose and it doesn't have special backdoors that give you a one-character solution to Hello World (for example).

Comment: Quines and Hello Worlds come up pretty often. And based on my recent data explorations they are among our most popular tags. As a result HQ9+, however limited, ends up being applicable to a significant number of challenges.

Comment: Pretty often? That's what flagging for duplicates is for. :-P

Comment: There have been several quine questions lately that neither I nor the community considered duplicates. E.g. the Mandoline/Guillotine Quine, the Meta Quine. Shall we flag all of those off? Is it "seen one quine, seen em all"?